# Use of the word "intrinsically" in mathematics.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, terminology

I am studying some algebraic geometry and surfaces of Riemann and reading some books... often appears an expression whose meaning is not clear to me. So I would like some help to understand this. The expression in question is "intrinsically".

I have separated some of the moments in which I have found (and continue) with doubts about what does it mean meant by the use of the word "intrinsically".

> 1) Nevertheless, we have, in fact, gained much, for 
>   we have defined multiplicities of $(d — 1)$-dimensional varieties 
>   *intrinsically*, in terms of properties of a ring of the function field 
>   of $V$, and this will be found to be of immense value in later
>   developments.
>
> 2) Recall that if $M=\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ is any complex torus, then the tangent spaces $\{T'_{\lambda}(M) \}_{\lambda\in M} $ are all naturally identified with $\mathbb{C}^g$. Thus if $X\subset M$ is any analytic subvariety of dimension $k$, $X^* = X — X_{\text{sing}}$ the smooth locus of $X$, we can define the Gauss map 
>   $$
> \begin{array}{llll}
> {\cal{G}}_ {X} :&X^*&\longrightarrow&G(k, g) \\
> &p&\longmapsto&T'_{p}(X)\subset T'_{p}(M)= \mathbb{C}^g.\\
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> We see immediately that $\cal G$ is *intrinsically* defined and that it does not vary if $X$ is translated in $M$.

So that's my question. What do authors mean by *intrinsically* in these two passages.

Thank You!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In (algebraic/differential) geometry an **intrinsic** property of a variety $X$ usually means one that does not depend on an embedding $X\hookrightarrow M$ into some larger variety.

For example, the properties of an affine variety that depend only on the ring of regular functions rather than some specific ideal.

The tangent bundle of a manifold $X$ is an **intrinsic** object and the normal bundle of $X\subset M$ is an **extrinsic** object.

I have to mention Gauss' Theorema Egregium which is called that way (by Gauss himself) because of the egregium (remarkable) fact that the Gaussian curvature is an **intrinsic** invariant despite it is defined **extrinsically**.